# Gentoo Gnome 3 Bluetooth cannot receive file

Tags: bluetooth, gentoo, gnome3

My system is Gentoo Gnome3, all up to date. After my phone has paired with my computer, I can send files to my phone, I can also browse the files on my phone. But I cannot use my phone to **send** a file to my computer. Also, in the **bluetooth manager**, I cannot find the **receive file** option.

I think I may missed something when compile Gnome3 or Bluetooth related utilities. But I cannot find out which one I have missed. I tried a lot of USE keywords and packages...none works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you found or are still looking for an answer - on my Fedora system you need the `gnome-user-share` package. The dialog it provides is this little number:

[image]

Which lets you set up your sharing preferences. This utility can also be used to set up other gnome sharing options.

You'll then notice the files appear - a notification icon can appear.